# Using VBA and Excel Power Query to import user-selected .txt data into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, import, powerquery

I'm trying to write a macro in Excel for Office 365 that prompts a user to select a .txt file, and then imports the text file to a new worksheet in an existing workbook, after deleting the first 4 rows of the file and splitting it up into columns. After recording a macro to do this, I get this, ridiculous first line:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="example sample", Formula:="let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & " _
Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents(""C:\Users\fakepath\example _
sample.txt""), null, null, 1252)})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "#""Removed Top Rows"" _ 
= Table.Skip(Source,4)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "#""Split Column by Character _ 
Transition"" = Table.SplitColumn(#""Removed Top Rows"", ""Column1"", Splitter. _ 
SplitTextByCharacterTransition({""0""..""9""}, (c) => not List.Contains({""0""..""9""}, c)), _ 
{""Column1.1"", ""Column1.2"", ""Column1.3"", ""Column1.4"", ""Column1.5"", ""Column1.6"", ""Column1.7"", _
 ""Column1.8"", ""Column1.9""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & " _ 
#""Split Column by Character Transition"""
```

Followed by

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:="OLEDB; _
      Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""example sample""; _
      Extended Properties=""""", Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [example sample]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "example_sample"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

I want to replace that hard-coded path in that first line of a code with a path of the user's choice but I am struggling to integrate that into that first line of insanity. In other examples, I've seen people precede that code with something like (from another answer on this site):

```
Dim fName As Variant

fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("txtfiles (*.txt), *.txt")
If fName = False Then
MsgBox "No File Was Selected"
Exit Sub
End If
```

and then replacing the hardcoded path with that fName, but after trying this by editing part of the first line from:

```
Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents(""C:\Users\fakepath\example sample.txt""), null, null, 1252)})
```

To

```
Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents(fName), null, null, 1252)})
```

the macro won't run. **Can anyone help me integrate a file with a given path chosen by the user into my recorded macro above?**

Comment: Where did you copy that first line from? It errors in my VBE.  I was expecting to be able to replace `""C:\Users\fakepath\example _
sample.txt""` with `" & somevariablefromfilepicker & "`

Comment: The first line was copied directly out of the macro that the "record macro" button created after I imported the text.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have Office 365, so I cannot test this:

```
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Dim fName As String
 
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
 
With fd
 
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt?", 1
    .Title = "Choose a Text file"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False               'select single file only
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Source Folder"   'change this accordingly
    
    'if a file is selected, assign to fName; exit if not
    If .Show = True Then
        fName = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
 
End With

'use fName, like so
'Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents(fName), null, null, 1252)})
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work.  I get the same errors in the debug as I did previously: Run-time error 1004 - Application or object defined error.  It doesn't like the last two lines of the with statement that I listed on the recorded macro:         
   .ListObject.DisplayName = "example_sample"
   .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 

... commenting them out doesn't work either, I get no data